# Android Studio: Preference android:summary="%s", but with a certain default summary

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

following problem: I have a dice application which should offer one, two or three dice to use. I am currently creating a DropDownPreference to change the value of the number of dice. I always want the current amount of dice to be displayed in the summary using "%s" in the android:summary attribute. The problem is, that the default summary entry seems always to be the first value of the "preference_dice" array.
Is there a way to display a certain default summary entry and afterwards displaying the currently selected amount of dice? I need to start with two dice by default.
Thanks!

DropDownPreference:

```
<DropDownPreference
        app:key="@string/preference_dice"
        android:title="@string/preference_dice_title"
        android:defaultValue="@string/preference_dice_2_value"
        android:entries="@array/preference_dice"
        android:entryValues="@array/preference_dice_values"
        android:summary="%s"
        />
```

Array for entries:

```
<string-array name="preference_dice">
    <item>@string/preference_dice_1</item>
    <item>@string/preference_dice_2</item>
    <item>@string/preference_dice_3</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it from code. Try the following way:

```
DropDownPreference preference = (DropDownPreference) findPreference ("preference_dice");
preference.setDefaultValue(preference_dice_1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, from my understanding setting the default value refers to the values array, and not to the entries array. The default value is already set in the xml. How can I set a default entry from the entries array?